# Formatting for written text, e.g. a sign

Tags: formatting

I've seen some passages use italics, others just use single/double quotation, or they use quotation with italics. So I'm a bit confused as to what the actual rule is regarding this.

So when describing what a person sees written on a sign, what is the correct format for describing what they see?

For example a sign reading: `Georgetown County Fair`. Which format would be correct?

> They approached a large sign reading 'Georgetown County Fair'
>
> They approached a large sign reading *'Georgetown County Fair'* `(single or double quotations?)`
>
> They approached a large sign reading *Georgetown County Fair*

Comment: What is the difference between A & B?

Comment: To be honest, i saw all three versions used in different books, and it really didn't matter much

Comment: Small caps is also an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have the Viewpoint Character Take Action**

> Bill approached the sign and read it: *Georgetown County Fair*.   He
>   scratched his head. "Georgetown?  I thought this was Mapleville."

Use italics for the sign if possible or use single-quotes.

**Even If You Don't Use the Word 'Read', It Works**

Notice how if you have the viewpoint character take the action, you don't even have to tell the reader that the character read the sign and it still makes sense.

> Bill approached the sign: *Georgetown County Fair*.   He scratched his
>   head. "Georgetown?  I thought this was Mapleville."